# How important is the interview confirmation email?

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process

I received a phone call from a company and I was convoked for an interview.

I was used to getting a confirmation email in similar cases, but I received nothing in this one instance.

Knowing that there was no mention for the email confirmation during the phone (I know the time and location), should I call them and ask them about it?

Comment: I think you should have it. At some places building security will not let you in without seeing an email confirmation on your phone. (Unless you are already in their system as visitor for that day).

Answer (score 9):

Confirmation emails are good practice, but not necessarily a standard for all companies.  Apparently, this place doesn't do them.

I would call them one or two days in advance of the interview just to confirm the time and place (or send them an email *requesting confirmation.*)  Otherwise, just make sure you show up on time.

Comment: Agree. Try to get it in writing, but if not, just follow-up and confirm over the phone. The worst thing that can happen is they cancel. It'd suck but you just keep looking. It's not too much of a big deal.

Answer (score 1):

An email confirming the information is ideal.

If you don't get an email, **or the confirmation email doesn't contain the details**, I would feel much safer with a *phone conversation confirming* the location and times.

Answer (score 0):

You can try sending an email seeking some clarifications on the role/company, where you can mention the interview about to happen. In case they do reply, you will have a written commitment. Do call them up a day or 2 before the agreed date, as suggested by others